# I want to animate the form in that particular div it self

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to disappear my form in that particular div it self, but my form is moving throughout the browser width...please help me..

#### css

```
#div {
    position : relative;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#888;
    margin-left:25%;
    text-align : center;
    padding:5%;
    margin-top:100px;
}
#main {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    border-top :10%;
}
```

#### js

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var name1 = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        $("#main").animate({"left":"-=1000px"},"fast",function(){
            $(this).after("Thank you"+" "+ name1+"."+ "<br>" + "Your email is" + " " + email);
        });
    });
});
```

#### html

```
<div id="div">
    <div id="main">
        <h3>Personal Details</h3>
        Name<input type="text" style="margin-left:10%" id="name"/><br><br>
        Email<input type="text" style="margin-left:11%"id="email"/><br><br>
        <button id="submit">submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('form').hide()`? but I don't see form in your html. Your heading says _I want to animate the form_, your comment _I want to disappear my form_. Which one is correct?

Comment: i want to hide div id #main...how can i?

Comment: `div#div`? That's funny.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the overflow property of the div that contains your form to hidden:

```
#div {
    position : relative;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#888;
    margin-left:
    text-align : center;
    padding:5%;
    margin-top:100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This will hide any elements that are outside of the dimensions you specified for your div.

Comment: now i want animate $(this).after("Thank you"+" "+ name1+"."+ "<br>" + "Your email is" + " " + email) from right side

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: hidden` to your div.

**CSS**

```
#div {
    ...
    overflow: hidden;
    ...
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/2BDc5/)

#### EDIT

[**See this**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/CaUdF/)

Comment: now i want animate $(this).after("Thank you"+" "+ name1+"."+ "<br>" + "Your email is" + " " + email) from right side

Comment: i didn't get idea please help me....after animating #div i have to get some confirmation message from right side to center ....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        var name1 = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        $("#div").animate({
            "left": "1000px"
        }, "fast", function () {
            $(this).after("Thank you" + " " + name1 + "." + "<br>" + "Your email is" + " " + email);
            $(this).css("display", "none");
        });
    });
});
```

`#main` will disappear after it finishes sliding to the left.

Here's the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JudeDuran/VC4Yn/).**